# How we can do User Interface Design in Eclipse?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I'm a flex programmer who has just started to learn android today, successfully starting my learning with a hello world program.

How can we do user interface design for android in Eclipse? In flex we have xml-based components (mxml) for doing this. Does Eclipse have any similar design method or any design mode (like dot net) doing design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse provide a XML editor. Just open a XML, and can drag Form widgets, texts, images, gadgets....

The basic structure work with Layout, [OFFICIAL TUTORIAL](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html), study about them

[Another good tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-layout/)

[Android advance design](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) <-- Very userful

Hope it help!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use droiddraw from [this](http://www.droiddraw.org). Also you have android XML layout Editor in eclipse where you can add layouts and widgets. For making custom widgets and layouts you need more java and android skills ^^ .